# Μonotony of $h(x) = (x-2)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{3}{x}$ using definition

Tags: calculus, analysis

Study the monotony of $h(x) = (x-2)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{3}{x}$ using the definition of monotony. (No derivatives allowed)

EDITED

1st of all let me point out that this is not homework.A student of mine with no knowledge of derivatives asked me about its monotony and that's why I posted it . I started of course with the restriction $x\geq 2$. The problem occurred cause $f(x) =\frac{3}{x},x\geq 2$  is decreasing and $f(x) = (x-2)^{\frac{1}{2}},x\geq 2$ is increasing .Using  [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-2)%5E(1%2F2)+%2B+3%2Fx) I discovered that $h(x)$ is increasing when $x\geq 2$. So my conclusion was that for every $x,y \in (2,\infty) , x\neq y$ $ $, $f(x)-f(y) \geq g(x)-g(y)$ (something that could be used for proving the statement using the definition of monotony). But without using derivatives is it possible to prove such a thing? Or should I tell him that with his knowledge he can't study the function's monotony for sure?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. $g(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$ is increasing and $h(x) = {a\over x}$ is also increasing if $a<0$. Thus the sum is also increasing.

---

Say $x>y$, then

$$f(x)-f(y) = \sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{y-2}+3/x-3/y = {x-y \over \sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{y-2}} -{3(x-y)\over xy} = (x-y)g(x,y)$$

where $$g(x,y) = {1 \over \sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{y-2}} -{3\over xy}$$

Now try to find if $g(x,y)$ is always positive or always negative.

Comment: I think that this problem is even harder than the 1st one. But I have the feeling that I should transfer the problem to complex numbers

Comment: Why, what will you do with the complex numbers?